# How to disable Programmatically Android 12 Elastic Scroll Animation

Tags: android, kotlin

how can I turn off the elastic scroll effect that comes with android 12?

Best regards

[image]

Answer (score 7):

try to add to your "scrollable" `View` in XML

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

or by code

```
scrollbableView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER)
```

[`setOverScrollMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setOverScrollMode(int)) is a method of `View`, so it may be set for all scrollable `View`s like `ScrollView`, `ListView`, `RecyclerView` etc.